# Why does my code become slow after processing a large dataset?

Tags: java

I have a Java program, which basically reads from a file line by line and stores the lines into a set. The file contains more than 30000000 lines. My program runs fast at the beginning but slow down after processing 20000000 lines and even too slow to wait. Can somebody explains why this would happen and how can I speed up the program again?

Thanks.

```
public void returnTop100Phases() {
    Set<Phase> phaseTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Phase>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Phase o1, Phase o2) {
            int diff = o2.count - o1.count;
            if (diff == 0) {
                return o1.phase.compareTo(o2.phase);
            } else {
                return diff > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        int lineCount = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("output")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineCount++;
            if (lineCount % 10000 == 0) {
                System.out.println(lineCount);
            }
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\t");
            phaseTreeSet.add(new Phase(tokens[0], Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])));
        }
        br.close();
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        Iterator<Phase> iterator = phaseTreeSet.iterator();
        int n = 100;
        while (n > 0 && iterator.hasNext()) {
            Phase phase = iterator.next();
            out.print(phase.phase + "\t" + phase.count + "\n");
            n--;
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about some code? You should use a way to read line by line and not store the entire file in memory if it's too big. It might happen that garbage collection at the end does more then your application code.

Comment: Is your code doing something like "for each line, check it against all the previous lines"?

Comment: The more items you put into your TreeSet, the more comparisons have to be performed when inserting a new item. It shouldn't be surprising that thing become "slow" when you're talking about 30 million items.

Comment: @f1sh I don't think that is the case, because add operation of TreeSet is logarithmic time operation. log(30 million) is less around 25.

Comment: I'd check garbage collections. You may be filling up your heap.

Comment: Can you provide Phase's compareTo() function? Need to know if it is consuming any time.

Comment: BTW, if your aim is just to get the first 100 elements, don't keep the whole set in memory. After adding each element, check if the set size is > 100, and if so, use `pollLast` to remove the highest element.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you so much! After keep the size of 100, my program will not exceed the heap size and GC is not involved frequently which slows my program down.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the runtime behaviour this is clearly a memory issue. Actually my tests even broke after around 5M with 'GC overhaed limit exeeded' on Java8. If I limit the size of the phaseTreeSet by adding

```
if (phaseTreeSet.size() > 100) { phaseTreeSet.pollLast(); }
```

it runs through quickly. The point why it gets that slow is, it uses more memory, and thus the garbage collection takes longer. But every time before it takes more memory it has to do a big garbage collection again. Obviously there's quite some memory to take, and every time it gets a bit slower...

To get faster you need to get the stuff out of memory. Maybe by keeping only top Phases like I did, or by using kind of a database.